# Rolling median in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, median, percentile

I have monthly expenditure data in BigQuery for some customers, with the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS monthly_spend (
  user_id int,
  transaction_month DATE,
  spend float
);

INSERT INTO monthly_spend VALUES
(1, '2021-01-01', 0),
(1, '2021-02-01', 1),
(1, '2021-03-01', 1),
(1, '2021-04-01', 2),
(1, '2021-05-01', 5),
(2, '2021-01-01', 5),
(2, '2021-02-01', 0),
(2, '2021-03-01', 1),
(2, '2021-04-01', 2),
(2, '2021-05-01', 2);
```

I'm trying to calculate the rolling median of the monthly expenditure using the following query:

```sql
select 
    user_id,
    transaction_month,
    avg(spend) over(partition by user_id order by transaction_month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_avg_spend,
    percentile_cont(spend, 0.5) over(partition by user_id order by transaction_month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_median_spend,
from monthly_spend
```

However, I get the following error:

```sql
Window ORDER BY is not allowed for analytic function percentile_cont at [69:63]
```

Is there a way to calculate a rolling median (without the current row) in BigQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
select 
  user_id,
  transaction_month,
  rolling_avg_spend,
  (select distinct percentile_cont(spend, 0.5) over() 
   from unnest(rolling_spends) spend
  ) as rolling_median_spend
from (
  select 
    user_id,
    transaction_month,
    avg(spend) over(partition by user_id order by transaction_month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_avg_spend,
    array_agg(spend) over(partition by user_id order by transaction_month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as rolling_spends,
  from monthly_spend  
)
```