# Rolling median grouped by user id

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a lot of client IDs and the value of the transaction. I want to find the median by client in the last 30 days. I tried this way:

```
    SELECT client_id, day, max(mov_avg_30d) as max
FROM (
  SELECT client_id,DATE(datetime_column) day,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(amount,0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(DATE(datetime_column)) RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS median_30d
  FROM table
)
group by client_id, day
```

But I got this error:

> Window ORDER BY is not allowed for analytic function percentile_cont at [4:78

Comment: I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465132/rolling-median-in-bigquery if not can you give sample input and expected output?