# BigQuery aggregating moving window with PERCENTILE_CONT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a relatively complex query I would like to modify. It aggregates a table with multiple measurements by multiple sensors. The aggregation is done per sensor ID and the way to aggregate is different for the different signals. Below you find a minimal example. The real table has many more signals and different aggregations, but I included the relevant parts here (including the useles `WHERE` clause in the main query):

```
-- create table and fill in content
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE my_project.my_db.my_table (
  timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  id INT64,
  value1 FLOAT64,
  value2 FLOAT64
);

INSERT INTO my_project.my_db.my_table (timestamp, id, value1, value2) VALUES
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', 1, 0.0001, 20),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:01 UTC', 1, 0,      25),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:02 UTC', 1, 0.001,  30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:05 UTC', 1, 0.002,  30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:06 UTC', 1, 1,      30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:08 UTC', 1, 0.0001, 30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:09 UTC', 1, 0.0005, 30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:10 UTC', 1, 0.0001, 30),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:05 UTC', 2, 0,      80),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:06 UTC', 2, 0,      110),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:07 UTC', 2, 0,      120),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:09 UTC', 2, 0.003,  130),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:10 UTC', 2, 0.003,  90),
  (TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:11 UTC', 2, 0,      80);

-- subqueries
WITH second_agg AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(*) AS second_agg_count
  FROM
    my_project.my_db.my_table
  WHERE
    value2 > 100
  GROUP BY
    id
),
first_agg AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(first_agg_val) as first_agg_max
    FROM  (
        SELECT
          id,
          AVG(value1) OVER (
            PARTITION BY id
            ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp)
            RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
          ) AS first_agg_val
      FROM my_project.my_db.my_table
      )
       GROUP BY id
)

-- main query
SELECT
  t.id,
  MIN(t.value1) AS min_v1,
  MIN(t.timestamp) AS min_time,
  ANY_VALUE(IFNULL(sa.second_agg_count, 0)) AS second_agg_count,
  ANY_VALUE(IFNULL(fa.first_agg_max, 0)) AS first_agg_val
FROM
  my_project.my_db.my_table AS t
LEFT JOIN second_agg AS sa ON t.id = sa.id
LEFT JOIN first_agg AS fa ON t.id = fa.id
WHERE t.id < 10
GROUP BY t.id
```

`value1` is a bit noisy and I filter it with the moving average and then take the maximum. Since the average can be affected by outliers, I'd like to use `PERCENTILE_CONT` instead of `AVG` in the subquery `first_agg`. With this I could calculate the moving median or any other percentile that works well with the data.

Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. I saw a similar issue in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465132/rolling-median-in-bigquery), but I don't see how I can apply the solution to my example above.

Does anybody have some hints on how to do that?

In case it matters, I'm running my queries from Python with SQLAlchemy and I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing your subquery like this, where I modified the SQL query to calculate a moving percentile using `PERCENTILE_CONT` within a window function by first aggregating values into an array and then applying the percentile function to this array for each window.

**Create a JavaScript UDF in BigQuery:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_project.my_db.calculate_percentile(arr ARRAY<FLOAT64>, percentile FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
arr.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
var index = (arr.length - 1) * percentile;
var lower = Math.floor(index);
var upper = Math.ceil(index);
var weight = index % 1;
if (upper >= arr.length) return arr[lower];
return arr[lower] * (1 - weight) + arr[upper] * weight;
""";
```

**Modify Your Query to Use the UDF:**

```
WITH first_agg AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(first_agg_val) as first_agg_max
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      my_project.my_db.calculate_percentile(
        ARRAY_AGG(value1) OVER (
          PARTITION BY id
          ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp)
          RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ),
        0.5
      ) AS first_agg_val
    FROM my_project.my_db.my_table
  )
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  first_agg
WHERE
  <your_conditions>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this query doesn't work when I run it in BigQuery Studio (in the GCP console) since it produces the error "Query error: Window ORDER BY is not allowed for analytic function percentile_cont"

Comment: Updated - make sure you replace <your_conditions>

Comment: That looks promising, but I get the error "Query error: No matching signature for aggregate function PERCENTILE_CONT for argument types: ARRAY<FLOAT64>, FLOAT64..."

Comment: Updated try that.